# Delete a table row is not working with jquery on button click

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have problem when I click on button the table row is not deleted **tr id** and **button id** are both same value. please tell where I am doing wrong

```
<tr id="<?php echo $result->id;?>">

  <td><input type="text" name="feature[]" class="text-input medium-input datepickur" value="<?php echo $result->feature;?>" /></td>

  <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="<?php echo $result->id;?>" class="btn btn-danger button_remove">X</button></td>

</tr>
```

*Jquery code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button_remove').click(function() {
      var btn_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#' + btn_id + '').remove();
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: tr id and button id is same means rule violation don't do this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` need to be unique per element if you are going to use them in `jQuery`, and hense your code is not working (As `tr` and `td` sharing same value for `id`).

Simplify you code through [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.button_remove').click(function(){ 
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

Note:- Remove `id` from `tr` and `td` both. As it's not needed at all. It will make your `HTML` structure correct and cleaner.

Comment: @Arslan  glad to help you :):). Cheers :):)

Comment: Yeah I know it after 5 minutes I do it

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are using same id for `tr` and `button`....Try to use `data-attributes` here

```
<tr id="<?php echo $result->id;?>">
  <td><input type="text" name="feature[]" class="text-input medium-input datepickur" value="<?php echo $result->feature;?>" /></td>
  <td><button type="button" name="remove" data-row="<?php echo $result->id;?>" class="btn btn-danger button_remove">X</button></td>
<tr>
```

And then use jQuery like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button_remove').click(function() {
    var btn_id = $(this).data("row");
    $('#' + btn_id + '').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: Your code is correct but actually this much is not needed. only `.closest()` will do the job in a single line without any `id` or `data-attribute`.You can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button_remove').click(function() {
    $(this).parents().eq(1).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="1"/></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="button_remove">X</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="2"/></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="button_remove">X</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment